# Windows Form Application - Works in debugger but not when published

Tags: .net, winforms, installation, publish

I have made a basic application using Windows Forms (.Net) but I am having trouble getting it to work. When I run the program through visual studio debugger it works.

However when I publish it then try to install it, after running setup.exe it says plz wait a few minutes then disappears and does nothing. For publishing I picked the "From a CD or DVD Rom" option.

In Event Viewer I get the following error:
https://www.pastiebin.com/6291f0f764207

I am guessing its related to the database somehow. I am using a local .mdf database. My connection string is as follows:

"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\localDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

Comment: Check Event Viewer for possible crashes

Comment: Ok I checked Event Viewer. I am getting 2 errors. One is a .Net and one is an Application Error.

The .Net error:
https://www.pastiebin.com/6291f0f764207

Comment: It means you didn't deploy the DB correctly, or your app try to establish connection to a remote DB inaccessible from that device.

Comment: I am using a local .mdf database. Shouldn't that be shipped with the app when published?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: What edition of SqlServer did you install? Where is `|DataDirectory|` pointing to? Did you set it to the location where the `.mdf` file is stored (not the startup path of the application, since it could be `Program Files` or some other path where you don't have write access rights)?

Comment: SQL Server Express LocalDB has its runtime. If you don't install that along with your installer, such errors are expected, https://www.sqlshack.com/install-microsoft-sql-server-express-localdb/

Comment: I don't know where |DataDirectory| is pointing to. It must be whatever the default is.

Comment: The *default location* is `Application.StartupPath`. You don't want your db there. Move it after installation / first run to, e.g., `Application.CommonAppDataPath` (a path where your application always has read/write access) and set `|DataDirectory|` to that location (before the data layer expands it, i.e., before you initialize a Connection with that connection string).

Comment: I have written this in the constructor of the form:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("Data Directory", Application.CommonAppDataPath);

Is that what you meant for me to do? I am still getting the same error as before even with that line of code.

Comment: It's `"DataDirectory"`, not `"Data Directory"` (no spaces, unless it's a typo). The db has to be there -- Did you install the SqlLocalDb run-time? You can add the msi installer to the package and use msiexec to install it (e.g., `msiexec /i [some path]\SqlLocalDB.msi` or silently, as e.g., `msiexec /i [some path]\SqlLocalDB.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES` <- note that this also fails silently)

Comment: I have installed the SQLLocalDB run time. I don't understand the second part of your suggestion. Sorry I am fairly new to this.